# I need help on a query regarding fetching data from a database file

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a database where a lot of sensors are sending data. I need to extract the most recent data from Pin 21,20,16,12.
I have written this query but so far it only returns me the last 4 values of the database and not the latest from from all of these pins. What am I doing wrong?[image: Output of my query]

```
select * from Temperature where Pin in (21,20,16,12) and Module =1 order by S_No desc limit 4
```

[Click here to download Database file](https://files.fm/u/6jy2agjf.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to add group by Pin on the end.

```
select * from Temperature where Pin in (21,20,16,12) and Module =1 group by Pin
```

I am so stupid